# Decompiled Java class producing different output

Tags: java, decompiler

Out of curiosity I just decompiled below code using **DJ Java Decompiler** as well using **CAVAJ Java Decompiler**
( Java version is 1.7 )
here is the normal source code :

---

```
    byte a = 10;
    a = (byte) (a +1);

    byte b = 10;
    b = b++;

    byte c = 10;
    c +=c;

    System.out.printf("a=%d \t b=%d \t c=%d\n",a,b,c);
```

Which shows output as: **a=11        b=10      c=20**

---

---

And here is the decompiled one:

```
    byte a = 10;
    a++;
    byte b = 10;
    b++;
    b = b;
    byte c = 10;
    c += c;
    System.out.printf("a= %d \t b = %d \t c = %d\n", new Object[] {
        Byte.valueOf(a), Byte.valueOf(b), Byte.valueOf(c)
    });
```

Which when used as source code output as: **a=11        b=11      c=20**

---

To be more clear it has nothing to do with `byte` same thing happening for `int` as well and I even checked above codes in online compiler [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/NQ13U2) and giving the same output as mine.

So, is the decompiler producing wrong code or is something else ??

Comment: I don't get how the additional spaces disappeared from output in the second case.

Comment: @dystroy that might be the feature of Decompiler`s editor to format the code

Comment: This should probably be discussed in CAVAJ's forum as it looks as a decompilation bug.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I suppose he's concerned by the fact that the decompiler changed `b=b++;` in `b++;b=b;`.

Comment: Yep, looks like a CAVAJ bug. Nothing we can help with *here*.

Comment: So, it would be better to put on query to CAVAJ?

Comment: @sansix I think so. I don't know this software but I suppose a bug report would be the thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will give you short answer: yes, it seems, that *the decompiler is producing wrong code*.
Because this one:

```
byte b = 10;
b = b++;
```

has strongly predicted behavior (`b` will not change).

**UPD:** Furthermore, no one of decompilers can give you 100% warranty of the correctness of generated decompiled code.

**UPD-2:** Are you sure, that you provide us actual version of your code? Because this one:

```
byte aa = 10;
a = (byte) (a +1);
```

of course is a mistake. It even will not compile :)

**UPD-3** Well, I need to say, that `Jad` decompiler (Jad 1.5.8g for Windows 9x/NT/2000 on Intel platform) produces the same code:

```
    byte b = 10;
    b++;
    b = b;
```

...

```
    java.lang.System.out.printf("a=%d \t b=%d \t c=%d\n", new java.lang.Object[] {...
```

**But** this is not surprising: **Cavaj Java decompiler uses Jad as its Java decompiling engine**.

**Conclusion:** Consider this behavior as a feature/bug of `Jad` decompiler, which is far from a perfection.

Comment: Wait 10 minutes, I'll check it by my self :)

Comment: @dystroy No they are of same class. BTW what made you think that

Comment: @sansix please view my UPD-2, there is some mistake in your code.

Comment: @Andremoniy +1 agreed with `b = b++;` this has predicted behaviour so might it be the case of decompiler bug

Comment: @dystroy is also info for you: I checked this case, it is really Jad's defect.

Comment: On the other hand, they'll probably explain that their decompiler helped OP find a bug in his code...

Comment: thanks @-dystroy and @Andremoniy I will report it to CAVAJ and if got any reply will post it here

Answer (score -2):

This is not about decompiler. When you compile a code using java compiler, in some cases, the compiler changes your code and optimize it to another code that does not change the result. Your code is:

```
byte a = 10;
a = (byte) (a + 1);
```

In this case, java compiler knows that there is no need to type cast between byte and byte and because of it, the compiler tries to remove your typecast and in this process, it replaces your code with closest code that it can understand. This is the compiler output:

```
byte a = 10;
a++;
```

So, this is not about decompile process. The java compiler changes your code.

Comment: so you meant to say `a = (byte) (a + 1);` here type cast is not required?

Comment: Dear, we are talking about this one: `b = b++;`

Comment: The answer is same. `b = b++;` changes during compilation process not decompile. This code will replace with `b++;` and yes, there is no need to a typecast.

Comment: When you write a code like `byte a = 0; a = (byte) (a + 1);` the compiler knows that you are trying to do `a++;` and it will change your code and optimize it to `a++;` in your version, typecast required but in compiled version it is not required and the result is same. Then simply compiler changes your code to optimized version.

Comment: Some distributions of the Java Developer's Kit include an alternate Java compiler called javac_g. This version of the Java compiler generates code without some of the internal optimizations performed by the standard javac compiler. If this compiler is in your JDK distribution, be sure to use it when you are compiling code for debugging. Otherwise, stick with the javac compiler for all release code.

Comment: @SasanYavari Replacing `b = b++;` with `b++; b = b;` isn't an optimization.